# Reference Request: Does $\lambda_\min\|x\|^2 \leq x^TPx \leq \lambda_\max\|x\|^2$ hold for positive semidefinite matrix?

Tags: inequality, reference-request, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

From Chong and Zak's optimization text:

**Rayleigh's inequality:** if an $n \times n$ matrix $P$ is real symmetric positive definite then

$$\lambda_\min\|x\|^2 \leq x^TPx \leq \lambda_\max\|x\|^2$$

Does the above inequality still hold if $P$ is positive semidefinite instead? Can someone cite a reference that would be very helpful!

Comment: Sure if $\lambda_{min}$ can be zero.

Comment: @JackyChong Did you write the book?

Comment: No. I definitely did not.

Comment: @JackyChong It's such a good book, thank you for everything professor

Comment: I'm only a grad student.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P$ is real and symmetric then the eigenvalues are real and there is an
orthogonal matrix (of eigenvectors) $Q$ such that $Q^T P Q = \Lambda$, where
$\Lambda$ is a diagonal matrix of eigenvalues.

Then $\langle x, P x \rangle = \langle Q^T x, \Lambda Q^T x \rangle = \sum_k \lambda_k [Q^Tx]_k^2$ and so
$\lambda_\min \|x\|^2 = \lambda_\min \|Q^Tx\|^2 = \sum_k \lambda_\min [Q^Tx]_k^2 \le \sum_k \lambda_k [Q^Tx]_k^2 = \langle x, P x \rangle$,
and similarly for the $\max$ eigenvalue, mutatis mutandis.

Comment: Not even necessarily positive semidefinite or definite

Comment: Any real symmetric (or Hermitian, for that matter).